# php array find matching pairs

Tags: php, arrays

Working on a simple poker script in PHP and need a way to determine if the player has TWO PAIRS of cards.

I have the players cards stored in an array ($hand) like:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [face] => k
        [suit] => d
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [face] => 6
        [suit] => s
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [face] => 6
        [suit] => h
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [face] => 4
        [suit] => d
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [face] => 7
        [suit] => h
    )
)
```

So if he had 2 aces, it wouldnt register, but if he had 2 aces and 2 kings, or 2 3's and 2 4's then it would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pair = 0;
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($hand) - 1; $i++) {
    for($j = $i+1; $j < sizeof($hand); $j++) {
        if(($hand[$i][face]) == ($hand[$j][face])) { 
            $pair++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to return `$pair` as 4 every time no matter what cards.